# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.cloud' jupyter notbook python 3.8.0

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to use cloud storage python library in a Jupyter notebook.

I am running a virtual env with python 3.8.0 (don't know if can be related but I'm on a mac with an M1 chip but running my terminal in Rosetta mode).

I ran `pip install google-cloud-storage` which worked, but when I launch Jupyter notebook and run `from google.cloud import storage` I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.cloud'`.

This is my first question here, so please advice if the question isn't clear or if I am missing relevant information.

Comment: Are you using same environment in both the cases?

Comment: I am @Shradha, that's why it so weird. However I did get an answer below that solved it, I just don't understand why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this command inside the jupyter notebook

```
!pip install google-cloud-storage
```

then

```
from google.cloud import storage
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! Do you know why that worked while installing from terminal didn't?